# Centos 7 Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux Additions kernel modules

Tags: centos, virtualbox, boot

Recently I ran updates on one of my Centos 7 Development Environments (server) which is running though Parallels on Mac OSX. Now, when I went to start the VM recently I received this output:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux Additions kernel modules.
See 'systemctl status vboxadd.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux Additions service.
See 'systemctl status vboxadd-service.service' for details.
```

See here below for the full output:

[image: Centos 7 output]

It does not boot, it freezes at the last shown output and never continues.

I've seen this issue before, it crept up on one of my other Virtual Machines, and after hours of research now in 2 separate events, I wanted to reach out to see if anyone knows how to go about solving this - I can't find documentation on it anywhere, and I'm not using Virtual Box I'm using Parallels.

How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

So, answered this one thanks to a friend.

When doing a kernel update, you have to update parallels tools apparently. The issue is, when updating the kernel the video drivers got crushed, VBox Addons seem like the are part of the Parallels tools suite, so the issue here was that it was hanging up because the system couldn't find a screen as a result of not having the correct video drivers.

Mounting the Parallels tools suite and updating, resolved the issue.

Comment: install `DKMS` from the EPEL respository; that is *dynamic kernel module support* and will preserve [rebuild] any installed kernel modules when doing a `yum update` which updates the linux kernel.  A common problem when using the nvidia graphics driver for example, if not using DKMS one would have to manually reinstall nvidia after a kernel update otherwise the result is a black screen frozen system upon boot because the nvidia kernel module is lost and nouveau is blacklisted thus no graphics support.

Comment: have DKMS installed prior to installing any other *parallel tools* and then when installing those tools they will get registered with DKMS and you won't have to worry about them later on whenever a linux kernel update happens.